# Parsing request JSON in Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra

I am having some difficulty with parsing the JSON from a request to my Sinatra application:

```
response = JSON.pretty_generate(request.env)
reply = response["rack.request.form_hash"]
```

results in reply just returning:

```
rack.request.form_hash
```

as a string rather than just the relevant part of the response:

```
   {...
     "rack.request.form_hash": {
   "token": "token",
   "team_id": "team",
   "team_domain": "teamname",
   "service_id": "service",
   "channel_id": "channel",
   "channel_name": "testing-webhooks",
   "timestamp": "1424480976.000910",
   "user_id": "U029W1WF2",
   "user_name": "myusername",
   "text": "checkeverything",
   "trigger_word": "checkeverything"
 },
 ...}
```

which is within the JSON request object I'm trying to parse. When I use:

```
response["rack.request.form_hash"]["user_name"]
```

there is nothing returned. The following is returned in my log:

```
 App 1662 stdout: 
App 1640 stderr: JSON::ParserError - 746: unexpected token at 'No text specified':
```

So it looks like it's not iterating properly, or perhaps can't access it.

I've looked through other documentation and other posts, but found nothing that worked for me, but I am definitely overlooking something, but I'm not sure what.

What is the best way to parse this nested array in a request to Sinatra?

Comment: I forgot to remove it; it was just something I tried at one point. Updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it :

```
res = JSON.parse( JSON.generate(request.env) )
res.class
# => Hash
res["rack.url_scheme"]
# => http
```

The reason is that the JSON.generate only generates JSON syntax for objects and arrays in a string. Then you need to parse the generated JSON string into a hash in Ruby with JSON.parse.

Comment: Thanks! This worked as well; I was actually able to access the data I wanted by adding "to_json" to request.env. I didn't realize JSON.parse was producing a hash until I found an error deeper in my log

Comment: Nice ! Btw, I checked out 'to_json', got it that it's an alternative to JSON.generate. But it supports more Ruby classes than just objects and arrays (and a shorter one too !).